# How to install the Cryengine SDK?

Tags: software-installation

Support was recently announced for complete Linux support for Cryengine. When coupled with the recent announcement of their "pay what you want" model, I think that this would be a very attractive offer for many out there. However, I cannot work out how to go about installing this on my Ubuntu 15.10 system.

Any advice would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

1. [Download Cryengine](https://www.cryengine.com/get-cryengine). (requires membership)
2. Install required dependencies.

   `$ sudo apt-get install build-essential python python-tk`
3. Change into the Cryengine directory and run the WAF build system.

   `$ cd ~/Downloads/cryengine-3.8.6`

   `$ ./cry_waf.sh build_linux_x64_gcc_debug --project-spec=gamesdk_and_tools`
4. Wait a while...
5. Finished! You should see binaries in the `BinLinux64gcc` directory.

Cryengine does not support the open source drivers, therefore you need to make sure that you have the proprietary drivers installed.

Comment: I can't see any option to download Cryengine... Just the launcher (which is a .exe)

Comment: You need to download the source code, not the launcher.

Comment: Where is the option to download the source? I can't find it

Answer (score 0):

Download from https://github.com/CRYTEK-CRYENGINE/CRYENGINE

and do the above mentioned cmds after extracting...

you should be downloading it after the 3rd cmd.

hope it solved.

Comment: Posting the actual instructions instead of just "read this link" would have been much better. Link only answers can become invalid if the link goes away or changes. Consider editing your question accordingly.